# css gradient text are not visible on Safari

Tags: html, css

am facing one issue on gradient css on web and android devices text are visible but on Safari its not showing at all. Please have look on both the screen shots.

I've checked with caniuse.com, and both [`-webkit-text-fill-color`](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_-webkit-text-fill-color) and [`background-clip: text`](https://caniuse.com/background-clip-text) are said to be supported both in Safari/Desktop as well as Safari/iOS.

```css
.gradient-effect {
  background: linear-gradient(240.86deg, #ff8329 0%, #ff007a 66.41%);
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  width: max-content;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}

.mine-box-title {
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 44px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  letter-spacing: -0.01em;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="mine-box-title gradient-effect">25 MILLION</h2>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an unresolved, open issue about this on the WebKit Bugzilla since 2017: [background-clip:text doesn't work with display:flex](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=169125). Apple has ignored this bug for 4 years, it will probably never be resolved.

Remove `display: flex` and it works:

```css
.gradient-effect {
  background: linear-gradient(240.86deg, #ff8329 0%, #ff007a 66.41%);
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  width: max-content;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}

.mine-box-title {
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 44px;
  letter-spacing: -0.01em;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="mine-box-title gradient-effect">25 MILLION</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks connexo its working